# Flexbox "align-items: center" not working on Chrome beta

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

In the example below, all stable flexbox-capable browsers render the page correctly.

See jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/v966v6pp/).

Because of `align-items: center;` the three colored blocks are evenly distributed in the `section` element:

[image: Firefox 48.0]

However, on the latest Chrome Beta (54) and Canary (55) versions, the same example gets rendered like this:

[image: Chrome beta 54]

Is this going to be the expected behaviour for `align-items` in the next versions of Chrome? Or is this a bug...

---

**UPDATE**

[Michael_B's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39450204/784341) cleared up the difference between `align-items` and `align-content` in this particular layout. His [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v966v6pp/7/) should be used for testing the layout.

Still, even with the correct flexbox property, Chrome beta and Canary are not rendering the layout the way they should be:

[image]

Comment: `align-items` is supposed to align items in a single row of items (hence the name). To center multiple lines (all content that is), use `align-content: center;`.

Comment: `align-content: center;` fixes the vertical centering problem, but the elements won't be evenly distributed this way.

Comment: Correct, I thought the question would be about the lines being at top instead of in the center. Did you try `align-content: space-around;`? Would that give you the expected result?

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/v966v6pp/5/ for an example.

Comment: No, this still gives the same rendering as my second screenshot on Chrome beta.

Comment: Unable to to replicate in Chrome Version 54.0.2840.16 beta-m (64-bit)

Comment: @Paulie_D, the issue is with Chrome only, not Firefox. Can you confirm that you see my first screenshot with 54.0.2840.16 beta? Because that would be weird. I have tested this on both OSX and Windows.

Comment: I get the standard look as per the top image from your JS fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to achieve the layout above is with `align-content: space-around` ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/v966v6pp/7/)).

When dealing with a multi-line flex container, `align-content` is the property to use.

*From the spec:*

> [**8.4. Packing Flex Lines: the `align-content`
>   property**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-content-property)
>
> The `align-content` property aligns a flex container’s lines within
>   the flex container when there is extra space in the cross-axis,
>   similar to how `justify-content` aligns individual items within the
>   main-axis.
>
> Note, this property has no effect on a single-line flex
>   container.
>
> Only multi-line flex containers ever have free space in the cross-axis
>   for lines to be aligned in, because in a single-line flex container
>   the sole line automatically stretches to fill the space.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification between `align-items` and `align-content`. I shall edit my question. But when I view your revised example with `align-content` on Chrome beta or Canary, the incorrect rendered layout still persists. Can you confirm this?

Comment: I can't access that version on this PC. Does it work in column-direction? https://jsfiddle.net/v966v6pp/10/

Comment: That works. So basically, for a layout like this, you have to introduce an extra element to contain the horizontal items.

Comment: It's an alternative solution, since the other method isn't working for you in some browsers.